# SQL Server 2005 Standard upgrade still appearing as Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have upgraded a SQL Server Express 2005 instance to Standard using the best practices described in other posts.  I have restarted the SQL Server but is still appears as Express in Management Studio and when executing select @@version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the cause of this problem.  I performed the upgrade again and it worked so it must have been something I missed during the initial attempy